# Master Locksmith

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics

## Description

> Master Locksmith has just finished the work of his life: a combination
>   lock so big and complex that no one will ever open it without knowing
>   the right combination. He's done testing it, so now all he has to do
>   is put the lock back into a neutral state, as to leave no trace of the
>   correct combination.
>
> The lock consists of some number of independently rotating discs. Each
>   disc has k numbers from `0` to `k-1` written around its circumference.
>   Consecutive numbers are adjacent to each other, i.e. `1` is between
>   `0` and `2`, and because the discs are circular, `0` is between `k-1`
>   and `1`. Discs can rotate freely in either direction. On the front of
>   the lock there's a marked bar going across all discs to indicate the
>   currently entered combination.
>
> Master Locksmith wants to reset the lock by rotating discs until all
>   show the same number. However, he's already itching to start work on
>   an even greater and more complicated lock, so he's not willing to
>   waste any time: he needs to choose such a number that it will take as
>   little time as possible to reach it. He can only rotate one disc at a
>   time, and it takes him `1` second to rotate it by one position. Given
>   `k` and the `initialState` of the lock, find the number he should
>   choose. If there are multiple possible answers, **return the smallest
>   one.**

## Example

> For `k = 10` and `initialState = [2, 7, 1]`
>
> the output should be `masterLocksmith(k, initialState) = 1`
>
> It takes 1 second for the first disc to reach `1 (2 → 1)`. It takes 4
>   seconds for the second disc to reach `1 (7 → 8 → 9 → 0 → 1)`. The
>   third disc is already at `1`. The whole process can be completed in
>   `5` seconds. Reaching any other number would take longer, so this is
>   the optimal solution.

## Constraints

Guaranteed constraints:

`3 ≤ k ≤ 10 ** 14`

`2 ≤ initialState.length ≤ 10**4`

`0 ≤ initialState[i] < k for all valid i`

## Code

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

def masterLocksmith(k, initial_state):
    occurence = defaultdict(int)
    for i in initial_state:
        occurence[i] += 1

    num_set = set(initial_state)
    num_set.add(0)

    shortest = {j: 0 for j in num_set}
    for i in occurence:
        for j in num_set:
            shortest[j] += min(abs(i-j), k - abs(i-j)) * occurence[i]
    return min([[k, shortest[k]] for k in shortest], key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]
```

The TLE's were really hard, I've tried some optimization but the best I could solve this in was still  \$ O(n * k) \$ which was not enough to complete the challenge. I am less concerned about readability but more how this can be sped up.

Comment: K is 10 ** 14 O(n * k) will never works more

Comment: What limits are you given on \$n\$ and \$k\$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've added the constraints

Comment: Is this from some public challenge? Can you add a link to the original problem?

Comment: @MartinR [source](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/Dfq9AGTczotsS9hqF)  You may need an account for this though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> def masterLocksmith(k, initial_state):
>     ...
>     for i in occurence:
>         for j in num_set:
>             shortest[j] += min(abs(i-j), k - abs(i-j)) * occurence[i]
>     return min([[k, shortest[k]] for k in shortest], key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]
> ```

The aliasing of `k` is not very helpful for readability; that last line is hard enough to decipher without confusion about the names. Another answer observed that using a running minimum would reduce memory usage and therefore possibly performance; in my opinion it would also be more readable.

---

> ```
> from collections import defaultdict
> ...
>     occurence = defaultdict(int)
>     for i in initial_state:
>         occurence[i] += 1
> ```

There's a specialised class for this:

```
from collections import Counter
...
    occurence = Counter(initial_state)
```

---

> the best I could solve this in was still \$O(n∗k)\$

I concur with Quuxplusone that it's actually \$O(n^2)\$. Looking at the small example case by hand, I think there's a reasonably straightforward way to do it in \$O(n \lg n)\$ time. This is just a sketch: I haven't implemented it.

Basically the task is to add a series of functions which look something like

```
  ^
 / \
/   \
     \   /
      \ /
       v
```

Note that there are two points of inflexion: at the initial value, and opposite the initial value. (Correctly handling odd vs even values of `k` will be a minor complication). Also note that a sum of piecewise linear functions is piecewise linear.

So you can first calculate in \$O(n)\$ time the score if the target number is `0` and the gradient of the sum at \$0\$. Then sort a list of inflexion points in \$O(n \lg n)\$ time and iterate through them, calculating the score by extrapolation from the previous one and the new gradient. Finally extrapolate to `k-1`.

Answer (score 6):

Style nits: misspelling of `occurence`, gratuitous renaming of the problem statement's `initialState` to `initial_state`.

I was initially skeptical of your algorithm, but I think I've convinced myself now that it's correct — even the initially mysterious addition of `0` to the `num_set`. Basically you're observing that if we have `m` dials set to the `M`th position, and `n` dials set to `N`th position, then it never makes sense to send them all to some position `POS` in the middle (`M < POS < N`). If `m > n` then we can save time by sending them all to `M`; if `m < n` then we save time by sending them all to `N`; and if `m = n` then sending them all to `POS` costs exactly the same amount as sending them all to either `M` *or* `N`. The one special case is when `m = n` and `M < 0 < N`, in which case the problem statement requires us to send them all to `0`... and that's why you special-case `num_set.add(0)`!

The above reasoning could productively have been recorded in a block comment.

Speed-wise, I see one obvious improvement and one possible improvement.

```
shortest = {j: 0 for j in num_set}
for i in occurence:
    for j in num_set:
        shortest[j] += min(abs(i-j), k - abs(i-j)) * occurence[i]
return min([[k, shortest[k]] for k in shortest], key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]
```

The obvious improvement is that you are repeatedly doing the lookup of `occurence[i]` (sic) inside your inner loop, even though you could have cached it in the outer loop. Let's do that. And similarly `shortest[k]`, even though I can't imagine *that* being a bottleneck:

```
shortest = {j: 0 for j in num_set}
for i, population in occurence.iteritems():
    for j in num_set:
        shortest[j] += min(abs(i-j), k - abs(i-j)) * population
return min(shortest.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1,0))[0]
```

The possible improvement is that you've got this dict `shortest` that you're keeping *only* so that you can take its minimum at the end. This is a classic pattern that's going to come up over and over, so you might as well learn it: *keep a running min.*

```
best = (0, float('inf'))
for j in num_set:
    score = 0
    for i, population in occurence.iteritems():
        score += min(abs(i-j), k - abs(i-j)) * population
    if score < best[1]:
        best = (j, score)
return best[0]
```

This isn't much of anything to look at, but it does completely eliminate the repeated computation of `shortest[j]` inside your inner loop.

If you'd included some test vectors in your question, then we could run them and see if these changes made any difference in the running time.

---

P.S. — You say your algorithm is `O(n*k)` (where `n` = `initialState.length`), but I believe your `num_set` optimization makes it actually `O(n*n)`. Since `n` is less than `10000`, you're doing on the order of 100 million ops here, so I'd guesstimate it should be doable in a couple of seconds, tops. How much time are you seeing it take, and on what kind of test cases?

Comment: This is incorrect, because when there are similar minimal distances, it should return the one with the lowest number. ie for `k:  10` and `initialStateinitia : [7, 8, 9, 3, 3]` it should return `7` not `9`

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:python-3.x] so it should be `items()` rather than `iteritems()`. Also , I think your running min code assumes that `num_set` is ordered (for the tie-breaker to work), and I don't believe that to be true.

Comment: After adding both improvements it will still not pass the TLE constraints

Comment: Ah, right, the tiebreaker should be `if (score < best[1]) or (score == best[1] and j < best[0])` — which can be just `if (score, j) < best`, if you flip around the order of `best`'s elements.

Comment: As for "Time Limit Exceeded": when I paste the Python code into https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/Dfq9AGTczotsS9hqF and click "Run Sample Tests," the site hangs forever (like, *way* more than the 4 seconds it claims is the time limit). But at the command line, running all 10 visible sample tests takes 0.073s *total*. So I think it's more likely a bug in the site's backend than a problem with Python. (For comparison, I also did the mechanical translation of this algorithm to C++17 and ran it; it also hung the site. So whatever problem it is, it's not Python-specific.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone That's the second time somebody told me this. Do you have an account? Because that might be the issue

Comment: No, I don't have an account. (I also wonder if your own account is encoded into the URL somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

Clicking through to [the source of the puzzle](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/Dfq9AGTczotsS9hqF), I observe that the problem statement does not require that you use Python; in fact it offers compiled languages such as C++ as possible alternatives. In the real world, many problems can be solved by *switching tools* than by trying to hack a solution using the first tool you thought of. You should consider the very real possibility that the puzzle is deliberately *not solveable in Python* given the constraints imposed by the problem statement.

Here's the mechanical translation to C++17 I mentioned in my previous comment.

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

long long masterLocksmith(long long k, std::vector<long long> initialState) {
    std::map<long long, long long> occurence;
    for (auto&& i : initialState)
        occurence[i] += 1;

    std::set<long long> num_set(initialState.begin(), initialState.end());
    num_set.insert(0);

    auto best = std::tuple(INFINITY, 0);
    for (auto&& j : num_set) {
        long long score = 0;
        for (auto&& [i, population] : occurence)
            score += std::min(std::abs(i-j), k - std::abs(i-j)) * population;
        if (std::tuple(score, j) < best)
            best = std::tuple(score, j);
    }
    return std::get<1>(best);
}
```

On my machine it takes 0.018s to run the 10 provided test cases; the Python version takes 0.073s. Neither takes anywhere close to 4 seconds. :)
OTOH, when I randomly generate a `k=10000, n=10000` test case and try running *that*, I see C++ taking 6.8s (and with `-O3` it takes 1.8s) whereas Python takes 76.1s. That's quite the penalty for using an interpreted language!

You can cut the running time of the naïve C++ code in half again by noticing that *iterating a map* inside your inner loop involves following a lot of pointers, and that's no good for your L1 cache. Replace the map with a cache-friendly `vector`, leaving the rest of the code the same:

```c++
std::map<long long, long long> temp;
for (auto&& i : initialState)
    temp[i] += 1;
std::vector<std::pair<long long, long long>> occurence(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

and the running time on my huge random test case drops to 3.5s (0.48s with `-O3`). I suspect that you could hack a similar cache-friendliness fix in Python, but I have no idea what it would look like; and anyway, if it halved your running time, you'd still be at 38s — a lot more hacks would be needed to get down to the compiled-language level.

Comment: Agreed Python may not be the best tool for the job :), but there are Python solutions that passed the test cases. I think a solution modeled after Peter Tayler will work.